# Xamarin forms Frame not working in android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need a design Like this....achieved in iOS but not working in android

[image]

please help me out

regards..

Comment: share your code and the results (screenshots) you get at iOS and Android

Comment: There is already a line in the default android active tab.

Comment: You just need to edit the tab XML to your needs like changing the active color. or create a custom renderer for android

Comment: i need a shadow not a line

Answer (score 1):

You can use below link to achieve your task.

https://asyncawait.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/bottom-menu-for-xamarin-forms-android/

Comment: its displaying the tabbed page thats not my requirement , i want to show  shadow ..above the bottom menu

Comment: then will see it might take time.

Comment: how to hide this bottombar in a certainpage

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a Nuget package for bottom navigation bar.
This will help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp_2F621Az0

Answer (score 0):

> In visual studio 2017.

I have the same issue.
Frame hasShadow property is not working in android project in Xamarin.Forms.

so i solve it by doing the following things.

```
1 - Update VS, xamarin SDK's.
2 - Create new project with default template.
3 - added install all the NuGet require packages.
4 - After installing all the packages i run this command on pakage console terminal "Update-Package".  
5 - Copy all the source code from the previous project.
```

Thats all.
Problem is fixed.

Comment: i will take a look on it